# Finding pods having issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

we are looking  to find the list of pods which is not in running state or having some issue.  Though below command pull pods detail including good ones, however we are targeting only bad ones

```
'kubectl get pods -A'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about it the kubectl way like Samuel suggested, or a more bash-oriented way.

Here are a few I use and when I use them

`kubectl get po -A | grep Pending` Looking for pods that have yet to schedule

`kubectl get po -A | grep -v Running` Looking for pods in a state other than Running

`kubectl get po -A -o wide | grep <IP>` Looking at all pods state for a given node

`grep` is a pretty powerful CLI tool with regex support that can help filter the output of `kubectl` commands.

Here's the man page for grep

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html

Comment: HI Nashluffy, Thanks for your response. "kubectl get po -A | grep -v Running" shows pods if anyone of its container is having some issue and that I was looking. "kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running " is not showing that result

Answer (score 3):

`kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed`

Or some better specification can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#viewing-finding-resources).

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thanks for response on this. I would like to know if pod is having 2 containers and one of them is having some issue example: STATUS is showing "CrashLoopBackOff" then "kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase!=Running " don't show that pod name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I use to find out which namespaces have problem pods and what the problems might be.  I call the script `notrunning`

```bash
kubectl get po -A --no-headers |
awk '
  BEGIN {
    SUBSEP=" "
    format = "%-20s %20s  %5s\n"
    printf format, "NAMESPACE", "STATUS", "COUNT"
  }
  !/Running/ {a[$1,$4]++}
  END {
    for (i in a) {split(i,t); printf format, t[1],t[2],a[i]}
  }
' | sort
```

I get results similar to this:

```bash
$ notrunning 

NAMESPACE                                                  STATUS  COUNT
namespace-01                                     InvalidImageName      2
namespace-02                                     InvalidImageName      1
namespace-02                                Init:ImagePullBackOff      1
namespace-03                                     CrashLoopBackOff      2
namespace-03                                     InvalidImageName      9
namespace-04                                    Init:ErrImagePull      1
```